# How do I subset data frame based on index numbers?

Tags: r

First off: I'm a newbie. Been looking around for an answer, and couldn't find it.

So I have a data frame of 50k + rows. What I want to do is to create two new data frames: one with row 0:28120 in the original data frame, and one with the rest.

Anyone know how to do this?

I've tried to do the following:

df.tory <- df[c (0:28120),]

df.labour <- df[c(28121:53814),]

It creates the new data frames, but when I summarise the data for the new data frame, all rows are included (ones that are not supposed to be there displayed with 0 in their values)

Comment: Try something like thos: 
`a1 = df[1:10,];
a2 = df[10:20,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `slice` from `tidyverse` to select just the rows you need by index.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  slice(1:28120)

df2 <- df %>% 
  slice(28121:53814)
```

or for the latter you can use

```
df2 <- df %>%
  slice(28121:n())
```

to specify all the remaining rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the range directly when subsetting, e.g.

```
cutoff <- 28120
df.tory <- df[1:cutoff, ]
df.labour <- df[(cutoff+1):nrow(df), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that indices in R start with 1, not 0. Try the following:

```
inds1 <- 1:28120
```

Then find the rest with:

```
inds2 <- setdiff(inds1, 1:nrow(df))
```

You can then define the two dataframes as:

```
df1 <- df[inds1, ]
df2 <- df[inds2, ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to create my two data frames this way. But I still have the issue of the excluded rows being included in my frequency tables. It seems the rows are still there somehow, just with 0 in their values. This is the case despite having the right number of observations listed in my environment..

Comment: Also, for some reason, the total observations in the two new data frames do not match up to the total for the original one. Some observations somehow go missing in the process...

Comment: Please include sample code for the way you compute the frequency tables.